# How to create a single legend for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I am trying to replicate the following plot but with a different set of data:

[image: Plot]

My current plot has everything you see except the legend in the top right corner. I am having a hard time figuring out how I am supposed to add this in with my current code:

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.title('Task Switches and Avg Task Switches by Timestep', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Task Switches', fontsize=9)
plt.xlim(-35, timestep_num + 35)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, timestep_num+1, 50), fontsize=-1, color='white')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 61, 20), fontsize=6)
plt.plot([stepsum_list[i][6] for i in range(len(stepsum_list))], color='royalblue', 
linewidth=0.7, linestyle='', marker='.', markersize=1)
plt.plot([stepsum_list[i][6]/(i+1) for i in range(len(stepsum_list))], color='limegreen', 
linewidth=0.6,)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.title('Task Demand per Timestep by Task', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Task Demand', fontsize=9)
plt.xlim(-35, timestep_num + 35)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, timestep_num+1, 50), fontsize=-1, color='white')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 6, 1), fontsize=6)
plt.plot([stepdem_list[i][1] for i in range(len(stepdem_list))], color='darkorange', 
linewidth=0.7, linestyle='', marker='.', markersize=1)
plt.plot([stepdem_list[i][2] for i in range(len(stepdem_list))], color='yellowgreen', 
linewidth=0.7, linestyle='', marker='.', markersize=1)
plt.plot([stepdem_list[i][3] for i in range(len(stepdem_list))], color='purple', 
linewidth=0.7, linestyle='', marker='.', markersize=1)
plt.plot([stepdem_list[i][4] for i in range(len(stepdem_list))], color='blue', linewidth=0.7, 
linestyle='', marker='.', markersize=1)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.title('Target and Tracker Movement',fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Movement', fontsize=9)
plt.xlabel('Timesteps', fontsize=9)
plt.xlim(-35, timestep_num + 35)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, timestep_num+1, 50), fontsize=8)
plt.yticks(np.arange(-10, 11, 10), fontsize=6)
plt.plot([stepsum_list[i][4] for i in range(len(stepsum_list))], color='blue', linewidth=.5)
plt.plot([stepsum_list[i][2] for i in range(len(stepsum_list))], color='red', linewidth=.5)

fig.align_labels()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)
plt.savefig('prog02_output.png')
plt.show
```

I apologize for all of the repetitive code, I'm brand new to Python and this is my first time making a plot so I don't know all of the tricks just yet. I have found the function `figlegend()`, but I'm confused if this is what I am going to want to use, and if so how the parameters are working. Placing the legend in the correct spot (aligned with the top subplot) is also something I am trying to do, but can't seem to figure out.

I'm not asking anyone to write any code or rewrite what I have. Just for someone to point me in the right direction, whether that be explaining a function and what parameters it can take, or what might need to be changed in my current code to use `figlegend()`.

Comment: For people to try and provide an answer that works for your example, it would be helpful if you included some mock data that would demonstrate the result you're getting.

Comment: First, you'll want to add a `label` keyword argument to everything you're plotting. Then look into [`Axes.get_legend_handles_labels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way I plot legends with my plots in Matplotlib is via the [`Axes.legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) function, shown below:
[image: Plot]

The source code is

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,2],[2,1,0], c='r', label='Plot 1')
ax.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,2], c='b', label='Plot 2')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

After you add labels to each of the data traces in your plot via the `label` keyword argument, then you can add a legend to the figure with

```py
plt.gca().legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your try to put more 3 variables, you can do this:

```py
    lns1 = plt.plot(x,y)
    lns2 = plt.plot(x2,y)
    lns3 = plt.plot(x3,y)
    lns = lns1+lns2+lns3+lns4
    
    labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
    
    plt.figure()
```

When you go to plot, use this:

```
    ax.legend(lns,labs,loc='lower center')
```